# MeteorJS observe when the timestamp changes

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to execute a function that will execute when the 'latestReportTime' key on my Schema changes and reached 2 minutes. I tried using observe() but it doesn't seem to be recognizing the changes. Please help!

Comment: We need a lot more detail to answer this with code. Is this a global or in a template? Can you show an example document along with the collection name? By "key on my Schema" you mean the value associated with that key on a specific document?

Comment: please share some of your code snippet so that we understand what is going wrong and what needs to be done.

Comment: it is within the template

the schema that I want to observe is the key timeOfRating with the type of date. Here's the code snippet:


http://pastebin.com/weGcdysn